# How to open a graphical file exporer in a home dir of a different user?

Tags: nautilus, users, .desktop

Installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (default user: abc)

Need to open a file explorer with read/write rights for user xyz in his home

How does the .desktop shortcut for this look like?

Comment: Do you already have read-write rights there or do you want to open the file explorer as admin or user `xyz`?

Comment: I have a .deskop shortcut for a cmd line with this entry: Exec=bash -c 'su -l  xyz'

Comment: When I enter ' bash -c 'su -l xyz'  ' into the command line of user abc and then after the user switch ' nautilus ' I get the following error: No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(nautilus:128672): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:09:11.441: cannot open display: :0

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no `gksudo` anymore, we'll use `pkexec`, which is part of `polkit`.

The following shell script will run nautilus as user xyz on the current display:

```
#!/bin/sh
xhost +SI:localuser:xyz
pkexec --user xyz env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY nautilus
xhost -SI:localuser:xyz
```

The `pkexec` line executes `env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY nautilus` as user `xyz`. We need to specify the `$DISPLAY` variable, because pkexec explicitly doesn't (see [man pkexec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pkexec.1.html) for more information).

`xhost +SI:localuser:xyz` permits user xyz to use the current display, the last command revokes that permission.

Now you can either run the script on its own or specify it in a `.desktop` file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! Worked!  However two things: a) when I call it from user abc I always have to authenticate as user abc. Is this normal? Can the passwd be saved / passed somehow (because it's alredy abc's desktop showing) b)  I've put it to a .desktop shortcut. When I open it a shell window starts. When I close the shell nautilus quits as well. How can I fix this?